# Cannot Open .Sparsebundle

Tags: mac, hard-drive, backup, time-machine, sparsebundle

My computer crashed few days ago, I took it to computer store and they told me that the logic board is damaged but the hard drive is fine. So they migrated all files from old mac to a new mac. All users are there as before, hard drive data are there for all users, except one user-"User1". when I log in to User1, there are no files, as if it has been erased. After digging into hidden files from main Admin user, I found "User1.sparsebundle" file that has 137GB. So one thing that came into my mind is that the account for this particular user were stored as in image disk with name User1. When I open the "User1.sparsebundle", I get the following error:

" image not recognized "

[image]

Is there a way to open it and see the content of the User1.sparsebundle image? 
Your assistance is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem myself, in few super easy steps, here's how:

-Right click on user1.sparsebundle -> get info, then make sure your user has the permission to open it
     (if not then click on the lock at lower right of "user1.sparsebundle" info window enter your password and add the user you want it to be shared with.)

-hook up a new external disk to mac and set it up as a time machine disk.

-copy the "user1.sparsebundle" into it

-once files are copied, open external hard drive and open "user1.sparsebundle" file 
( you may need to enter your password do so and files will be mounted as a disk in your finder )

I think the key point is to have an external hard drive set as time machine and copy sparsebundle file into it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mount it changing it's permissions with `chmod a+rw . -R`and `find . -type d -exec chmod a+x {} \;`